# UWP/Windows 10 scenario - How to open multiple Photo windows with multiple images launched with Launcher class?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

In an app of mine, I have noticed that when I open multiple image files with the `Launcher` class, they just open in the same Photo window, overriding itself.

Do you know a way on how to open each image file in a new Photo window?

I already know that the `Launcher` functions have an option class that can be added to specify launching options... and I have already played a little bit with it, but I didn't come up with any solution.

Do you know something else or how to use the `Launcher` option class?

Thank you so much and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know a way on how to open each image file in a new Photo window?

You mean how to launch multiple Photo application windows via `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()`?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#photos-app-uri-scheme) is Microsoft's public link to the Photo application, there is no content about launching multiple windows.

---

But you can write multi-window code for your app, open another window to display it when you open the image.

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(ShowImagePage), null);   
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
        Window.Current.Activate();

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
}
```

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) about multiple views.

Best regards.